# org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem not found

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, mapreduce

After configuring Hive 2 with MapReduce, HDFS and S3. I can query data from S3, however when I use a MR operation like JOIN or MAX, Hive raises the following error:

```
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderCreationException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:97)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.handleRecordReaderCreationException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.java:57)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(HadoopShimsSecure.java:269)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.<init>(HadoopShimsSecure.java:216)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileInputFormatShim.getRecordReader(HadoopShimsSecure.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getRecordReader(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:681)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:169)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:432)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(HadoopShimsSecure.java:255)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2654)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.<init>(LineRecordReader.java:108)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveRecordReader.<init>(CombineHiveRecordReader.java:67)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
... 26 more
```

Im trying to do the following query:

```
SELECT MAX(Column1) from table1;
```

And I have already added s3 and the access key to the following files:

***hdfs-site.xml***

```
 <property> <name>fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId</name> <value>USER</value>
 </property> 
 <property> <name>fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
 <value>SECRET_KEY</value> </property>
```

***core-site.dfs***

```
<property>
<name>fs.s3.impl</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>fs.s3n.impl</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId</name>
<value>USER</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
<value>SECRET_KEY</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

***mapred-site.xml***

```
<property>
<name>fs.s3.impl</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>fs.s3n.impl</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem</value>
</property>
```

***hadoop-env.sh***

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*
```

***hive-site.xml***

```
<property>
<name>fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId</name>
<value>USER</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
<value>SECRET_KEY</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like hadoop-aws isn't on the classpath. It may be in tools/lib.

Comment: In hadoop-env, Im exporting tools/lib and the directory contains: hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar

Comment: well, judging by that stack trace, it hasn't got as far as Hive. (Somehow) you're going to have to get hive to print its classpath, then you are going to need to work out how to get it on there. BTW, as you are on Hadoop 2.7.3, switch to the s3a:// client if you can: better performance, v4 auth endpoints and much more